# What does "best block" mean?

Tags: parity

In my Parity status screen, it says "best block", followed by a recent block number. What doest that mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I think** (while i am not a parity user) that:

**Recent block** is the last block that was mined. 
**best block** is the last valid block with the highest amount of accumulated work invested in it.

Comment: Now I've been watching it for a while, it seems that "best block" is always the last block. Maybe it should say "last block".

Comment: they could be different if your  recent block belong to another fork than the longest chain. so the best block belong always to the main chain unlike the recent one which is probably belonging to the longest chain.

Comment: What @BadrBellaj said is correct.